# Video encoded and sent from Android can not be played in iOS Telegram

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, telegram

Telegram use `MeidaCodec` to encode video from Android API 16. It works fine from API 18. But there are an error in API 16, 17. Video encoded and sent from Android cannot be played in iOS.
I think the problem is in process converting color between output of decoder codec and input of encoder codec.
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/2114024ab1d9cf209916bcdb3a4a7d44e51a3b0c/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/MediaController.java#L3223

My application currently uses `ffmpeg` to encode video. But it's too slow. `MediaCodec` is much faster than `ffmpeg`. But it only works well from API 18.
 Can anyone solve the problem video cannot be played in iOS? Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved the issue somehow?